# Unable to get total records of date in php mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Working with PHP and MySQL, I have the following table "employee_time", which contains date information in "day/hour/minute" format.

```
id      em_id           diff
1       1170            1:2:0
2       1170            0:2:5
...
A
```

and i want to get total of "diff" (varchar) whose id is ='1170'
I tried with following query but giving me wrong result

```
SELECT SUM(diff) as total_time from employee_time where em_id='1170'
```

expected result should be

```
1:4:5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `substring_index` function to extract (day, hour, minutes) values from the 'diff' string as the following:

```
select em_id, concat_ws(':', sum(d), sum(h), sum(m)) total_time
from
(
  select *,
   substring_index(diff,':', 1) d,
   substring_index(substring_index(diff,':', 2),':', -1) h,
   substring_index(diff,':', -1) m
 from employee_time
) t
where em_id = 1170
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/69Kl7elc)